# Get directory of the file which included another file in PHP

Tags: php, web

I got two files:

get_path.php:

```
function get_path() {
    echo basename(__FILE__); 
}
```

main.php

```
require("get_path.php");

get_path();
// This echos out "get_path.php", however i want it to echo out main.php
```

Does somebody know how to achieve this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just use the basename function direct from main.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your function is as stated in the `get_path.php` file you can rewrite your function like this:

```
function get_path() {   
    $included_files = get_included_files();     
    foreach($included_files as $k=>$value){
        if($value===__FILE__) return basename($included_files[$k-1]);
    }
}
```

I use return but you can use `echo` and just after `break;` this return the file which directly `include get_path.php` but if you want the first level path.I mean the first file which include all the other files you can use :

```
function getFirstLevelPath(){
    $included_files = get_included_files();     
    return basename($included_files[0]);

}
```

the output of your main will be now 
:

```
main.php
```